# Post to 2 (two) Wordpress websites at the same time

Tags: wordpress

I'm running two Wordpress websites on two different servers with two different domain names.

Sometimes I would like to be able to post on one website and have that post push to the other Wordpress website too so I don't have to copy-paste again.

I've tried searching but there's nothing concrete that came up. Is there a solution to this issue? If it's a paid plugin that works, that's even better. I would prefer a paid plugin over a hack since updating it for every Wordpress update is going to be a pain.

regards,

Comment: Wouldn't doing that cause lower SEO rankings due to Duplicated Content?

Comment: Doesn't matter.